# HTML <iframe> tag in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I have a situation where my `iframe` tag loads in both Firefox and Safari, but refuses to load in Google Chrome. Does anyone know of a workaround?

edit: after researching a bit, it appears this is a Google Chrome security feature.

```
<p align="center"><iframe style="width:30%;height:500px"; src="data:text/html;base64,binary-data-here"; frameBorder="0"; position:relative></iframe></p>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid HTML, maybe update that. Also, what is the error message you receive in Chrome?

Comment: There isn't an error. The figure (that is base64 encoded into the iframe) refuses to load in google chrome, but loads in firefox and safari.

Comment: You need to check your network log and debug log. Either the request isn't going through or there is a security error printed to your console.

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to use JS to create a new iframe element, assign the `src` attribute a base64 encoded string, and add the element to the current document.

It works for me in Chrome.

```
// create new iframe element
let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

// add base64 src
iframe.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";

// add iframe to some element of your choosing in the document
element.appendChild(iframe)
```

Comment: I tried this and still am not seeing my figure in Chrome, but works in Firefox and Safari. How is this different from what I posted above?

Comment: I've tested this in Chrome DevTools, using JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/2w93f645/), and in a static HTML page on a server. They all work for me in the latest version of Chrome on Windows. I'm not sure what to tell you.

Comment: In response to `How is this different from what I posted above?`, your example was pure HTML, while mine  was pure JS. Both get converted into DOM objects eventually, but they take different paths to get there, and it's possible that security policies in browsers may be applied to one but not the other. I hope that's helpful.